# Passing objects to another function's parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

This could be a beginner level question but I could not found an answer here.

I have a function prototype like this:

```
function Car (name, brand) {
     this.name = name;
     this.brand = brand;
}
```

I have another function that takes arguments from the Car function. Here names array are holding all the name(s) and brands array holding all the brand(s). Now I would like to return an array of Car object like "i3" : "BMW", "AMG GT" : "Marcedes"  that is a car info of each car or an empty array if the arrays’ lengths are unequal or zero, or if any array is null.

```
function createCar(names, brands) {

}
```

The main purpose of this to learn passing array from one function to another and return relevant info as key value pair.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: function createCar should just have car as parameter. You also need to be clear about naming and functionality, whether it is the plural (cars, brands, names) or singular, create one car a time.

Comment: **The main purpose of this to learn passing array from one function to another**... You are not learning, you are asking use for a solution. Try it yourself and come back with more code

Comment: @Weedoze, "asking use for a solution" is another way of learning, I believe. I wanted some logic here as I am just started learning and trying things on my own and I did not find any answer online that answers this. I have noted you view for my future question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

1. You'd learn much better if you'd try something more than just a function with an empty body;
2. Relying, or even expecting for arrays of the same length, even if they are validated, is inefficient. It would be a better idea to have a single array with information grouped in an object (something like `[{carName: "A8", carBrand:"Audi"}, ...]`)
3. Even if you validated that the arrays are of the same length, that doesn't mean that their content is what you'd expect. Maybe you get numbers, or even functions, instead of strings. You'd better validate for that too.

**To the code**

You want to create more cars, not just one, so make sure that is reflected in your code

`function createCars`

Now that we got that out of the way, here's the code, annotated with what we're doing:

```
function createCars(names, brands) {
    // before blindly checking if names or brands are of the same length
    // check if names and brands are arrays in the first place
    if (!(Array.isArray(names) && Array.isArray(brands))) 
        throw new Error("Please provide the 'names' and 'brands' array");

    // do we have expected lengths? 
    if (names.length == 0 || brands.length == 0 || brands.length != names.length) 
        throw new Error("Please provide arrays of the same length, with at least one item");

    // As you saw, I threw errors in case something went wrong. Doing that 
    // helped me to make sure that if we ever reach THIS line, then we have
    // expected values. If something will go wrong, JS will stop the execution anyway

    // Ok so all good. Next, since We'll return something
    // let's reflect that in our code. Initialize with significant name:
    var carsToReturn = [];

    // Let's loop and create the cars for each element
    for (var i = 0; i<names.length;i++){
        carsToReturn.push(new Car(names[i], brands[i]));
    }

    // Done. Simple, right? :). 

    // All that's left is to return the cars
    return carsToReturn;
}
```

Comment: 1. I should elaborate my function but I did not because I thought it might cloud-up my question, as I seen other parts of SO. 2. Thanks for this point which I needed. 3. Checking whether an array or not is a good suggestion.I wanted logic but Many thanks for your elaborated answer.

Comment: @user9219381 - glad it helped. I know I've been through similar questions when I began learning JS. Now, as far as stack overflow is concerned, whenever you ask a question be sure to also mark the answers appropriately (upvote if you feel they are useful and/or accept them if they answered your question)